# How to plot on complex plane with Mandelbrot set

Tags: plotting, graphics, fractals

I essentially want to treat the Mandelbrot set plot as a normal plot so that I can plot arrows and points on top of it.

This is what I want to do but it gives me an error:

```
Show[MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.5 - 2.5 I, 2.5 + 2.5 I}], Point[0 + 0 I]]
```

This does not work either:

```
Show[MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.5 - 2.5 I, 2.5 + 2.5 I}], Point[0, 0]]
```

How can I display and annotate this plot?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MandelbrotSetPlot` *does* produce a normal plot.  "Normal" here means that the result has [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `Graphics`.  Recommended reading on the term "head": [Everything is an expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html).

`Show` can be used to combine expressions which have the head `Graphics`.

The line below has two problems:

```
Show[MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.5 - 2.5 I, 2.5 + 2.5 I}], Point[0, 0]]
```

1. `Point[0,0]` is not a `Graphics` expression.  It should be enclosed in `Graphics` before using it in `Show`.
2. `Point[0,0]` is not correct syntax.  Use `Point[{0,0}]`, as shown in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Point.html).

This will work:

```
Show[MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.5 - 2.5 I, 2.5 + 2.5 I}], Graphics[{Point[{1, 0}]}]]
```

An alternative solution is [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
MandelbrotSetPlot[{-2.5 - 2.5 I, 2.5 + 2.5 I}, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

Here I also changed the colour and size of the point to make is visible over a black background.

Additional reading:

- [The structure of graphics](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheStructureOfGraphics.html)

Comment: A kindly patient and complete answer to a user's first question. :-)

Comment: I am such a noob. I've used points numerous times yet I didn't try that. Thanks anyway for you quick reply and next time I'll do a bit of research before posting it in.